# $X$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal is a closed subset of $X^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Consider $X^2$ with the product topology. Show that $X$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal $D = \{(x,y) \in X^2 \mid x=y\}$ is a closed subset of $X^2$.

Comment: This has been asked a billion times.

Comment: Can you please answer just one more time .I think its bit different from that one if not so can you share the answer

Comment: Click the link. Read the (multiple) answers.

Comment: I Could not find the link

Comment: It is the first comment to this question by Najib Idrissi.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Convince yourself that for $x \neq y$, finding distinct open neighborhoods $U_x$ and $U_y$ is the same as finding an open neighborhood of $(x,y) \in X \times X$, which does net meet the diagonal.

Comment: The downvoter might explain him/herself?

Comment: Sure: At almost 12k reputation, one would think you would recognize such obvious duplicates and not answer them. Especially if it's to give a hint answer like that.